# Default value for a property if not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

So in my properties file I've got something like:

`list.of.blacklist=xyz,pop,dum` etc. If in the event this property does not have any values I would like a default value of hukd. This is what i have in one of my constuctor args in my beans.xml file:

`<constructor-arg name="listOfBlacklist" value="#{'${list.of.blacklist}:HUKD'.split(',')}"/>`

Is this the correct syntax of declaring a default value when  populating a list of values from a property file?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a small modification to the syntax you are using, by adding the default value within ${}, right after the property with ':' , ie:

```
"#{'${list.of.blacklist:HUKD}'.split(',')}"
```

Add the default value within the curly braces itself as this operation happens in 2 steps:

1. a. Fetch the config value from the property using '${list.of.blacklist:HUKD}'

   b. if no value found, set the defualt value of HUKD, the value after : within curly ${}
2. Split this value with ',' using spel. The value obtained in step 1 is basically surrounded by #{'value from step 1'.split(',')}